# How to build WxPython in Tumbleweed?

Tags: python, linux, pip, wxpython

I have been trying to build the wxPython system, since there isnt a rpm for the version in suse, I have followed the instructions of [installation](https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html)

Literally:

- Make a temp directory
- `python3 -m venv builder_py
  source builder_py/bin/activate`
- Update wheel and setuptools

  pip install -U pip

pip install -U six wheel setuptools

- install wxPython `pip download wxPython`
- Make the build `pip wheel -v wxPython-4.0.1.tar.gz  2>&1 | tee build.log`

The ouput is posted [here](https://pastebin.com/ddTqnsbM), I dont understand the meaning of the output, previously, the dependencies were fulfilled via zypper and pip, since I try to compile the source without pip, but it didnt have success.

Then whats the meaning of the output, or alternatively, how can be build the package?
`
**UPDATE**
Veriifying the existence of wxPython-4.0.1.tar.gz in the working dir

```
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached wxPython-4.1.0.tar.gz (65.8 MB)
  Saved ./wxPython-4.1.0.tar.gz
```

and doing ls

```
Pillow-7.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl  six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
builder_py                                    wxPython-4.1.0.tar.gz
numpy-1.18.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

So I can confirm the tared source is present.

Comment: Are you sure `pip download wxPython` downloaded `wxPython-4.0.1.tar.gz`? I believe it's `wxPython-4.1.0.tar.gz`.

Comment: Issuing the comand pip download wxPython, shows the download of many packs, included wxPython-4.0.1.tar.gz.

Comment: Verify the file is in the current directory before running `pip wheel wxPython-4.0.1.tar.gz`